# A theorem about sequences Cauchy in measure (Folland's Book)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

I'm reading Folland's book, and I had a hard time following one of the proofs. I'm trying to understand the proof for:

Suppose that  $\{f_n\} \subset L^1$, and that $\{f_n\}$ is cauchy in measure. Then there is a measurable function $f$ such that $f_n \to f$ in measure, and there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ that converges to $f$ a.e.. Moreover, if also $f_n \to g$ in measure, then $g = f$ a.e..

Here is my attempted proof, in that I modified the written proof in the bits that I couldn't understand. Is this proof correct? (I'm especially worried about the $f^{-1}(B) = \left(\left(\bigcap_{l=k}^\infty \bigcup_{j=l}^\infty g_j^{-1}(B)\right) \cap F^c \right) \cup F \text{ if } 0 \in B$ part, and any error corrections are greatly appreciated.) $\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}$

As $f_n$ is cauchy in measure, we can choose a subsequence $\{g_j\} = \{f_{n_j}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ such that if $E_j = \{ x:\norm{g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x)} \ge 2^{-j}\}$, then $\mu(E_j) \le 2^{-j}$. If $F_k = \cup_{j=k}^\infty E_j$, then $\mu(F_k) \le \sum_k^\infty 2^{-j} = 2^{1-k}$. If $x$ is not in $F_k$, for $i \ge j \ge k$ (note that $\norm{g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x)} \le 2^{-j}$ in this case) $$\norm{g_j(x) - g_i(x)} \le \sum_{l = j}^{i-1} \norm{g_{l+1}(x) - g_l(x)} \le \sum_{l = j}^{i-1} 2^{-1} \le 2^{1-j}. $$
Thus $\{g_j\}$ is pointwise cauchy on $F_k^c$. Let $F = \bigcap_1^\infty F_k = \limsup E_j$. Then as $\mu(F_k) \le 2^{1-k}$, $\mu(F) = 0$. If we set $f(x) = \lim g_j(x)$ for $x \notin F$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in F$, then $f$ is measurable (explained below) and $g_j \to f$ a.e. (as $F$ is a null set).

$x \in F^c$, $x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty F_k^c$, note that $j \ge k$ by definition. So on such $x$, $g_j(x)$ is cauchy, so it converges.

For any borel set $B$,
$$f^{-1}(B) = \left(\left(\bigcap_{l=k}^\infty \bigcup_{j=l}^\infty g_j^{-1}(B)\right) \cap F^c \right) \cup F \text{ if } 0 \in B$$
$$f^{-1}(B) = \left(\left(\bigcap_{l=k}^\infty \bigcup_{j=l}^\infty g_j^{-1}(B)\right) \cap F^c \right)  \cup \emptyset \text{ if } 0 \notin B$$
For justification, $ a \in \left(\left(\bigcap_{l=k}^\infty \bigcup_{j=l}^\infty g_j^{-1}(B)\right) \cap F^c \right)$ $\iff$ $a \in g_j^{-1}(B)$ for infinitely many $j$. We need only show $g_j^{-1}(B)$ is a measurable set to conclude $f$ measurable. But this is immediate; as $g_j \in L^1$, there exists measurable and integrable $h_j$ and $h_j = g_j$ a.e., say on set $N$. Then $$ g_j^{-1}(B) = (h_j^{-1}(B) \cap N) \cup N_B$$ where $N_B \subset N$, so is a null set in a complete measure space. The measurability of $g_j$ thus follows from measurability of $h_j$.

From $\norm{g_j(x) - g_i(x)} \le 2^{1-j}$ that we proved above we obtain $\norm{g_j(x) - f(x)} \le 2^{1-j}$ for $x \notin F_k$ and $j \ge k$ (As $\norm{\cdot}$ is continuous, we can pass through limits, i.e. $\lim_{i \to \infty}$). $\{ \norm{g_j - f} \ge \epsilon\}$ is no larger than $F_k$ for large enough $k$, but as $\mu(F_k) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, we have that $g_j \to f$ in measure. Noting that $$ \{ x: \norm{f_n(x) -f(x)} \ge \epsilon\} \subset \{ x: \norm{f_n(x) - g_j(x)} \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\}\bigcup \{ x: \norm{g_j(x) - f(x)} \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\}$$ we conclude $f_n \to f$ in measure (As $f_n$ is cauchy in measure, $\{ x: \norm{f_n(x) - g_j(x)} \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\}$ has very small measure for large $n,j$ and as $g_j \to f$ in measure, $\{ x: \norm{g_j(x) - f(x)} \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\}$ has very small measure for large $j$.).

Finally, suppose $f_n \to g$ in measure. Similar to above, $$ \{ x: \norm{f(x) -g(x)} \ge \epsilon\} \subset \{ x: \norm{f_n(x) - f(x)} \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\}\bigcup \{ x: \norm{g(x) - f_n(x)} \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2}\}$$ for all n. Now we have $f_n \to f$ in measure as well, and using a similar process to above, we conclude that $\mu(\{ x: \norm{f(x) -g(x)} \ge \epsilon\}) = 0$ for all $\epsilon$ (by letting $n$ grow large). Letting $\epsilon$ tend to $0$ through some sequence of values, we conclude that $f=g$ a.e..

Comment: Hi Xita, it's true that the part you're worried about is off. For example, say we have $g_j \equiv 2^{-j}$, so that $f \equiv 0$. (Also, $F$ and each $E_j$ is empty in this setup.) Then take $B = (0, 1]$. On the one hand, we have $f^{-1}(B) = \emptyset$. But $g_j^{-1}(B)$ is the full domain space for every $j$. Therefore $(( \bigcap_{l = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{j = l}^{\infty} g_j^{-1}(B) ) \cap F^c) \cup \emptyset$ (or you can start the outer intersection at $l = k$ as written in the question, although I suspect that may have been a typo) is also the full domain space.

Comment: To show that $f$ is measurable, you don't necessarily have to write out a general expression for $f^{-1}(B)$. What may be a little easier is to show that $f$ is measurable on each of the sets $F$ and $F^c$.

Comment: @Jason, thank you for your comment. Apologies for the delayed response. $l=k$ wasn't a typo; it was intentional, although the proof above is my first draft so may not be too precise in its language and may have other typos. Also, I've done it both ways. It is easy to show that $f$ is measurable on each of the sets $F$, $F^c$. Anyway, thanks for your comment.